# Big O of MATLAB built-in functions

Tags: algorithm, matlab, time-complexity, big-o

I wrote the code for an algorithm, in which I used some MATLAB built-in functions such as `rand`, `max`, `norm`, `sin` and `cos`. Now I have to evaluate the computational complexity of my algorithm in big-O form.

I couldn't find the big-O complexity of any of these functions on the internet or anywhere else.

How should I compute the complexity of MATLAB built-in functions so I can get the code complexity? I can get the time-complexity through using `tic toc`, but how can I get the big-O complexity?

Comment: Unfortunately you don't have access to that.  Those functions wrap around LAPACK and the way MATLAB uses them is a trade secret.  You cannot directly evaluate Big O because you don't have access to the source.  You can only rely on timing - incrementally increasing the size of your data and seeing how much time it takes.  You can also assume the best case for a lot of the functions.  For example, `max` and `min` are most certainly `O(n)` as that is the best case scenario for most algorithms.  Basically if you want to evaluate Big O on a theoretical basis, you're SOL.

Comment: You can, however, make estimates. `max` and `norm` require at least `O(n)` time (assuming no pre-processing). `rand`, `sin` and `cos` are most likely `O(1)` operations. More complex operations may list the algorithm used in the documentation from which you can calculate the time complexity.

Comment: thanks guys, i ran a test code and notice that on the same vector, most time consuming function was rand, then abs, and then max. so if max is O(n), certainly rand and abs can not be O(1). however their time was so near and of the same order. so is it correct that i take all of them O(n)?

Comment: You can assume `rand` and `abs` are linear time as each input needs to be processed independently.

Comment: Note that “taking more time” is not equivalent to order notation. Big O is all about behavior in the worst case as the n increases. An order n function could take a million years on a single input and two million years on two inputs

Comment: It would be incorrect to approximate function order based solely on a single input vector